# how to skip one label having same class name of other in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, label, skip

How to skip one label having same class name of other in jquery

```
<label for="myCb1">test1</label>
<label for="myCb1">test</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCb1" value="1" />
```

when i try to invoke the label of myCb1 both are display so please help how to skip one label using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`:eq`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index) pseudo-selector as such:

```
$("label[for='myCb1']:eq(1)")
```

`:eq` allows you to specify the index of the found elements that you want to return. The index is **zero-based** (which means that the first element will be index `0`).

> [jQuery Docs: `:eq` pseudo-selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.class:first-child')`

This is if they are right next to each other like you just described.

Answer (score 1):

Either give them an id to uniquely identify them, or you can use a selector such as:

```
$("label[for=myCb1]:eq(0)") // Only selects the first label
$("label[for=myCb1]:eq(1)") // Only selects the second label
```